# Cannot start a bounty --a temporary problem?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

I am not able to start bounty on a question. When I click "start bounty" I get greeted by a pop-up that asks me how much reputation I will like to award. Then it asks for a reason. After that it asks me to put an optional comment and then that should be it.

But on that last screen, if I click "Start Bounty" nothing happens --the pop-up stays open and, as is obvious, bounty is not started.

I have tried Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari --none seem to work. Anything wrong here?

P.S:- I have checked the [FAQ](https://history.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty). I am not in violation of any terms for bounties.

Comment: I think the question also has to have been open for a while. The interface should keep you from getting that far in that case though.

Comment: @T.E.D. That is correct. For the first three days I saw "Eligible for bounty in 3/2/1 days". Then I saw "Start a bounty".

Comment: @T.E.D. Is there a way I can attract the dev. team to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried posting through the S/E link?  http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/help/other

Comment: @MichaelF Thanks very much. Just posted it there --let's see if this gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently (read: a couple days ago) deployed a fix for this issue.

Can you give it another try and see if you can post a bounty now? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it worked.